# Pass string of "<TableName>.<ColumnName>" as a Where() condition generates error: "No property or field '<TableName>' exists in type '<TableName>'"

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, dynamic-linq

Currently, I build query statement by using [dynamic-linq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/) library.

And I have an issue when I execute this query:

```
query = query.Where("Table1.Column2.Contains(@0)", new string[] { "test" });
```

FYI:

- `Table1`: a table name in my database
- `Column2`: a column name inside `Table1`

As a result, it throws an error:

> No property or field 'Table1' exists in type 'Table1'

I have made sure, the naming are correct. A friend of mine, he also uses exactly the same library and he can execute it successfully in different database, MSSQL 2014. I am using MSSQL 2008.

When I try to do it in different way like:

```
query = query.Where("Column2.Contains(@0)", new string[] { "test" });
```

It works fine..

I am wondering, in my case, I have to use the first approach instead. That's why, what am I doing wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that Dynamic Linq is still operating on *objects*, not passing what you write directly through to SQL?  So you can only add conditions on things that are *properties of the underlying object*.  Now these may be defined as being populated from various columns in a database, but they don't have to be...

I think you're basically trying to do this sort of thing:

```
class x
{
    int SomeProperty{get;set;}
}
...
...
var instance = new x();
instance.SomeProperty = 1;

//compile Error: x is not a property of an instance of x
if (instance.x.SomeProperty==1)  
{
   // ..Do things
}
```